# In the following code, why is "OUCH" alerted?

Tags: javascript

In the following javascript code, I set a timer after 2 seconds, in which the handler is a function which alerts 'doneMessage'. When the prompt occurs, the next line should execute after I enter something or cancel the prompt.

```
function setTimer(doneMessage, n) {

    setTimeout(function() {
            alert(doneMessage);
        }, n);

    prompt('Enter a number');
    doneMessage = "OUCH!";
}
setTimer("Cookies are done!", 2000);
```

So if I take more than 2 seconds on the 'prompt', the timer event should occur before the next line is executed. In this case 'doneMessage' should still be "Cookies are done!".

Why is "OUCH" alerted ?

Comment: Because you overwrite the doneMessage before the timeout is executed.

Comment: Isn't the timer 's handler function executed after 2s ? and i wasted more than 2 seconds in the 'prompt'

Comment: The prompt is “blocking”, the browser can not show the alert while you are still dealing with the prompt. The alert gets put on hold until you finish dealing with the prompt.

Comment: Does the prompt pause the execution of script ?

Comment: The `prompt()` blocks everything, and you can see that if you enter something fast. It still takes 2 sec. before the alert show, which means it block the timer as well.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {alert('abc'); }, 3000);
        prompt('Enter something');`                         cancel the prompt after 5 seconds, the alert shows as soon as you close the prompt. If timer was blocked it would take 3 sec after cancelling ?

Comment: The timer dosen't stop running ( basically it it just a timestamp, and if the execution of the timer function is blocked by the prompt, it will execute when the prompt is closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a single threaded language.

It cannot run more than 1 tasks at the same time.

Your current task is still being executed but held up by the prompt command.

Once you complete the prompt and exit the setTimer() function then that task is effectively finished.

At that point the doneMessage was set to "OUCH!"

Javascript is now free to do the next task.

Typically, it It loops all the timeout and see if there are any completed timer to execute and put them in a queue to execute next.

If you click on a button, it does not *always* immediately execute that button. It is place in the queue of task to execute next but given a high priority to make sure it is processed next. If Javascript wasn't currently in middle executing a task your button would be processed immediately.

Use the <input> tag and create your own prompt which is non-thread blocking and you will get the behaviour you want.

Comment: No, setTimeout does NOT create a new thread. It put the function in queue in the event loop. It is still the same thread.

Comment: So if you use setTimer(or some other event) inside a function, it's handler would be invoked after that function is completed ?

Comment: The timer countdown takes effect immediately - another word, it start counting down before the prompt has taken effect. After the prompt, when you continue the execution, if you have nested functions, all those nested functions must also be exited too. Eventually Javascript will run out of things to execute in the current task. When that happens it then goes through all the events such as mouse, keys, timers and decide what task to execute next. When your 2 seconds are up then that is when your timer function is executed.